# Overlay a div on HTML 5 video in firefox doesn't work?

Tags: html, css, video, html5-video

Basically I've:

```css
    .pofvv{
     position:relative;
     width:100%;
     height:100%;
     background:black;
     z-index:1;
    }
    .overlay{
     position:absolute;
     height:60px;
     width:100%;
     bottom:0px;
     background: white;
    z-index:2147483647;
    }
```

```html
<video class="pofvv" id="pofvv">
  <source src="wajid.MP4" type="video/mp4">
 </video>
 <div class="overlay"></div>
```

As You can see I've the maximum `z-index` on my `overlay` container which works on chrome and opera whether the video is full screen or not. The problem is with firefox which if the video went to fullscreen my `overlay` element goes below video. So I would really appreciated if someone could tell what is the cause and how to fix it.

All My Regards ( '.* )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this snippet.

```css
.pofvv{
     position:relative;
     width:100%;
     height:100%;
     background:black;
     z-index:1;
    }
    .overlay{
     position:absolute;
     height:60px;
     width:100%;
     bottom:0px;
     background: white;
    z-index:2147483647;
      top:50%;
    }
```

```html
<video class="pofvv" id="pofvv">
  <source src="wajid.MP4" type="video/mp4">
 </video>
<div class="overlay"></div>
```

Comment: First I'm sry I didn't see you post, Second This is what I mean But this does not overlay on firefox while video go to full screen mode!

Comment: you have set  width:100%;  height:100%; so its take full width

Comment: full width & height to it's parent div Not the full screen t, I need to overlay on full screen. I'm requesting the full screen mode with jquery `vid.requestFullscreen`. and then I need my `overlay` element to overlay in the video after `vid.requestFullscreen`.

Comment: like what? I got like more than 2000 lines, well to be precise This `overlay` element of mine contains my video controls, like pause, play volume and etc. so posting them too would confuse you all. I've you could tell me why this overlay is not placing in firefox video full screen mode, That will do it All.